# How to add a particular class to a li tag by searching its text

Tags: jquery

I have a list of `li` tags.I want to check whether there is any `li` tags that contains a particular text.If there is i need to add a class named `disabled` to that corresponding `li` tag that contains that particular text.Could someone please help me

```
<ul class="default">
      <li>Text 1</li>
      <li>Text 2</li>
      <li>Text 3</li>
      <li>Text 4</li>
      <li>Text 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? Don't you know how to select elements by text? Don't you know how to add a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('li:contains("Text 4")').addClass("test");
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkvJm/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery .contains()

```
$("li:contains(Text 1)")
```

Example here [jQuery :contains() Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_sel_contains)

Answer (score 0):

Ive made a prototype for that, Copy that after including jQuery :

```
//@Author Karl-André Gagnon
if(!$.fn.filterText) $.fn.filterText = function(text, caseSensitive){
    var returnedObj = $(),
        caseSensitive = caseSensitive || false,
        $this = $(this);
    if(typeof text == 'object'){
        for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
            if(typeof text[i] == 'string'){
                console.log(i);
                returnedObj = returnedObj.add($this.filter(function(){
                    var search = caseSensitive ? text[i] : new RegExp(text[i], 'i')
                    return $(this).text().search(search) != -1;
                }))

            }
        }
    }else if(typeof text == 'string'){
        returnedObj = returnedObj.add($this.filter(function(){
            var search = caseSensitive ? text : new RegExp(text, 'i')
            return $(this).text().search(search) != -1;
        }))
    }
    return returnedObj;
}
```

Then you can call it like that :

```
$('li').filterText(['text 1', 'text 2']).addClass('disable');
//Or
$('li').filterText('text 3').addClass('disable');
```

Also you can add a second aguemnt if you want to the to be case sensitive.

```
$('li').filterText('Text 3', true).addClass('disable');
```